# Output filename to be same as input with additional name in R

Tags: r, regex

I am using the raster package to process some raster files/satellite data. I have used the below to select the path and my input image:

```
inputfile <- choose.files(default = "D:\\March\\NewData\\2017", caption = "Select files",
                            multi = TRUE, filters = Filters,
                            index = nrow(Filters))
```

this gives:

```
inputfile = D:\\March\\NewData\\2017\\chlorophyll.tiff
```

To get my processed raster file saved in the same directory and same filename but with an additional word, I have to copy and paste:

```
D:\\March\\NewData\\2017\\chlorophyll.tiff
```

in the below (and manually add '_new')

```
writeRaster(stack_cor, "D:\\March\\NewData\\2017\\chlorophyll_new.tiff", format='GTiff',
```

As I need to do this repetitively, I'd like to get `inputfile` automatically and then just manually add `_new` to it - instead of having to copy and paste `inputfile` in the output, i.e. `writeRaster(........)` each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
fn <- "D:\\March\\NewData\\2017\\chlorophyll.tiff"
paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(fn), "_new.", tools::file_ext(fn))
# [1] "D:\\March\\NewData\\2017\\chlorophyll_new.tiff"
```

(The `tools` package is installed with base R, it's just not attached by default.)

Also,

```r
gsub("\\.tiff$", "_new.tiff", fn)
# [1] "D:\\March\\NewData\\2017\\chlorophyll_new.tiff"
```

If you have a multitude of possible file extensions, then

```r
gsub("\\.(tiff|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|something)$", "_new.tiff", fn)
# [1] "D:\\March\\NewData\\2017\\chlorophyll_new.tiff"
```

Comment: This works:fname <- paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(inputfile), "_new.", tools::file_ext(inputfile))
writeRaster(x=stack_cor, fname, format='GTiff', overwrite=TRUE)

Answer (score 1):

That's what [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) are for:

```
inputfile <- "D:\\March\\NewData\\2017\\chlorophyll.tiff"
outputfile <- gsub("\\.tiff$", "_new.tiff", inputfile)

outputfile
```

produces:

```
[1] "D:\\March\\NewData\\2017\\chlorophyll_new.tiff"
```